# Is registering a database as a DAC required to deploy DACPAC?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac, dac

Looking at the publish profile in my SSDT database project I see an option for RegisterDataTierApplication. It's not clear to me if this is a requirement in order for DACPAC deployment to work.

Comment: If it was, why would it be an option?

Comment: Yea, that's what I wondered. So I guess not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not required to publish a database project. It's more for when you have managed versions. I haven't used it for any of my normal database projects.

MS doesn't have a lot to say on their main page, but here's their short blurb:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/extract-publish-and-register-dacpac-files?view=sql-server-2017